# Web scraping dynamic content with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Im trying to scrape data from a site that generates its data via a javascript but I cant seem to locate the invoking script. When I look at the page source there is an in-page script that has a variable which has an array of the data I wish to retrieve but there is another script which contains all the codes for the various companies I wish to retrieve data from. This is what i've tried so far:

```
var url = 'http://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/ZAM/details';
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
    var digitalData = page.evaluate(function () {
            return window.digitalData;
        })page.then(function (digitalData) {
            console.log
        }
            ('DigtalData is ' + digitalData));
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Unfortunately the above script doesnt output anything. The script which contains the codes for the companies I want to get the data from I think is this:

```
var locationPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var companyCode = locationPath[locationPath.length - 1].trim();
var sectorCodes = {
    "MOQ": "soft",
    "1PG": "soft",
    "ONT": "heal",
    "1ST": "heal",
    "T3D": "food",
    "TGP": "real",
    "TIX": "real",
    "TDO": "ener",
    "DDD": "mate",
    "3PL": "cons",
    "4DS": "semi"
};

setTimeout(function () {
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        googletag.defineSlot('/76291182/ASX_leaderboard_com_info', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1450158832871-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/76291182/ASX_MREC_com_info', [[300, 250], [300, 600]], 'div-gpt-ad-1450158832871-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/76291182/ASX_MREC_lower_com_info', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1450158832871-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/76291182/ASX_skyscraper_com_info', [160, 600], 'div-gpt-ad-1450158832871-3').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/76291182/ASX_half_page_com_info', [300, 600], 'div-gpt-ad-1450158832871-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().setTargeting("cc", companyCode);

        if (typeof sectorCodes[companyCode] != 'undefined') {
            googletag.pubads().setTargeting('sec', sectorCodes[companyCode]);
        }
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
}, 2000);
```

This script seems to do a lot more than just contain the codes for the companies but its the only JS script I can find that has the company codes. I believe the data I want is from this script:

```
var currentURL = (document.URL);
var part = currentURL.split("/")[6];
// var dwsDTM = $('#company-code-title').text();

var digitalData = {
    "page": {
        "pageInfo": {
            "pageID": "3345",
            "pageName": "Company info " + part,
            "pageURL": window.location.href,
            "issueDate": "n/a",
            "updatedDate": "n/a",
            "brand": "ASX",
            "generator": "OpenText",
            "domain": "Website",
            "sysEnv": "",
            "delayType": "Normal"
        },
        "category": {
            "primaryCategory": "Prices and research",
            "subCategory1": "Company information",
            "subCategory2": "Company info " + part,
            "subCategory3": "",
            "pageType": ""
        },
        "productInfo": {}
    },
    "user": {
        "profileInfo": {
            "memberB2B": "",
            "businessMemberID": "",
            "memberRetail": "",
            "retailMemberID": ""
        },
        "version": "1.0",
        "events": [],
        "vendor": {
            "GoogleAnalytics": {
                "account": "UA-9950793-3",
                "eventCategory": ""
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I believe its generated to this HTML:

```
<div class="view-content" ui-view></div>
```

Im new to scraping dynamic content and this looks so hard to do. Could someone point me in the right direction to retrieve this data?
Thanks

UPDATE: So after a few hours of playing on the site I figured out that they use angularJS for their data call backs and upon further playing around I found the links they use to store their data. They have an API but I dont think its publicly available. In any case I think I can write a simple DOM Script to retrieve and format the data. Will keep you all posted

Comment: At the provided URL I see info on "ZAMANCO MINERALS LIMITED". What do you want to get from there again?

Comment: @Vaviloff unfortunately I could not retrieve any of the desired data I required, the ASX site has no API to access company data. When I used a simple DOM Parser I was only able to static data or data not generated via javascript

Comment: First and foremost, doing this is against their [Terms of Service](http://www.asx.com.au/about/terms-use.htm). So I would strongly advise aborting this. That said, the general pattern you'd be looking for in a situation like this is to use other phantomjs functions to interact with the page and wait for the content you need to be present before scraping it. Again though, I am not recommending using that here. It is against their TOS and you should respect that.

Comment: You are correct, ill post my solution and leave it at that. I appreciate the warning @GotDibbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. Utilising their API and using HTML DOM and PHP I was able to retrieve the data I wanted and then output the data to CSV. I cant discuss my code or the API because it would be in violation of their terms and service.